# Azure Web Forms and HTML to PDF converters

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, pdf-generation

If you are using Windows Azure Web Sites for deployment (not Cloud Services) and developing an ASP.net Web Forms application, is it possible to use a 3rd party HTML to PDF converter?  I'm starting to think I must convert to a Web Application instead of being a Web Form.  I'm kind of new to all of this, so I'd appreciate anyone's input.

If by chance there are 3rd party HTML to PDF converters that are compatible with Web Forms and Azure Web sites, that would be useful.  I'm rather happy with the site as-is, but I need to add in the ability to generate a PDF report and I don't fancy tearing up the code if I can avoid it.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the best solution I found was to use DocRaptor.com  Their webservice allows you to POST your HTML to their server and they echo back with the PDF.  This is the only means that will work on Azure Websites.  I'm in the midst of converting to a Cloud Service to get around the DocRaptor fees.  In the long run the Cloud Service is the better route if you are going to do tons of PDF conversions with DocRaptor.

Answer (score 6):

Subsequent to my comment 27-dec I had to find a solution and 8 cents per document wasn't an option for thousands of documents.  Eventually we build our own solution service http://www.html2pdfrocket.com and made it free.

We pretty much ended up doing exactly what you said - hosting it on Microsoft Azure Cloud Services - as you also discovered the Azure websites didn't have the flexibility or scalability to do what we needed but their cloud services is perfect for it.

Comment: Just curious, why could you not deploy this application on azure websites? What kind of issues did you face?

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra unfortunately the conversion dll's required GDI+ and after some digging a Microsoft engineer confirmed to me Azure Websites did not support this :(  Cloud services however does support it so it's a good choice for you.